# What do I need to connect to? (sql)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have some scripts from college to create a database. I'm new to pl/sql and when I try to execute those scripts it asks me to connect to a server. I don't know what server to connect or why. Shouldn't I be able to create a database without internet connection or server?

Comment: Added `oracle` tag based on the mentioning of `PL/SQL`

Comment: can you tell us how are you running the scripts?

Comment: Why are you asking us instead of your college? We've have literally **no idea** what these scripts do, nor what IT infrastructure your college uses or expects you to use.

Comment: Also, for future reference please tag your question with the database product - `[oracle]`, `[mysql]`, `[sql-server]`. Things like installation are different for each product, so being specific prevents people wasting their time providing the wrong answer and helps you get the right answer quicker.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to verify that the SQL Server service is running. You can do this by going to Start > Control Panel > Administrative Tools > Services, and checking that the service SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS) is running. If not, start it.
While you're in the services applet, also make sure that the service SQL Browser is started. If not, start it.
You need to make sure that SQL Server is allowed to use TCP/IP or named pipes. You can turn these on by opening the SQL Server Configuration Manager in Start > Programs > Microsoft SQL Server 2012 > Configuration Tools, and make sure that TCP/IP and Named Pipes are enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If oracle database installed on your PC, you can open start -> run windows and type there "sqlplus / as sysdba". When you get invite like "SQL>" you can execute scripts.

If you want to use remore database, you need login/password and database sid.
The text in Run window will look like "sqlplus login/password@sid", but you need to check correnct tnsnames.ora for your database sid in oracle client directory before.